# jQuery DataTable multiple value search

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have situation where I'm filtering values in column "Office" with selectbox where I can select multiple values. For example I want to filter "New York" and "San Francisco" in column "Office" so I expect only first row because it contains both values. My current code shows first row and other row because they contains "New York" or "San Francisco"

**Exmple**
http://live.datatables.net/fadixapi/1/edit?html,js,output

**Solved** 
    `selected = $("#"+selectId+' option:selected').map(function(){
                    return "(?=.*"+this.value+")";
                }).get();
 table.column(2).search("^.*" + search + ".*$",true).draw();`

Comment: This is difficult to answer without a test case. http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://live.datatables.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
table.column(2)
.search("^" + search + "$", column, true, false)
.draw() ;
```

Comment: in .search() what is column variable?